# What is the difference between B-spline curve, B-spline basis and B-spline function?

Tags: numerical-methods, curves, spline

What is the difference between B-spline curve, B-spline basis and B-spline function?
I have thought that: a B-spline basis is a basis for B-spline function while a B-spline curve is a linear combination of B-spline basis functions ($N_{k}^{m}(t)$) s.t: $P(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{L}P_k N_{k}^{m}(t)$. 
Is it all right what I have said or not?

Comment: I think what you said is correct. B in B-spline is "Basis". And the Spline lies in their span. I think some confusion arises as people think "spline" means some Bezier spline or variant.